# Multiple or statement can be written as in, any way for multiple and statement in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select * from Table1 where fieldname = 'a' or fieldname = 'b' or fieldname = 'c'
```

The above statement can be written as

```
select * from Table1 where fieldname in ('a', 'b', 'c')
```

Is there any way to shorthand 'and' statement

```
select * from Table1 where fieldname = 'a' and fieldname = 'b' and fieldname = 'c'
```

**Update**: Consider the situation

```
fieldname ID
--------------------
a         1   
a         2
b         3
c         4  
b         5
a         6
```

Comment: Condition is wrong. Result set will always be empty.

Comment: yes, this gives the same result: select * from table1 where 1=0

Comment: I think you have `AND` and `OR` confused...

Comment: You *might* be looking for "Relational Division", if you're in fact looking for multiple rows which together (for some other column) must match the conditions. Otherwise, as people have pointed out, there can be *no* row where `fieldname='a'` *and* `fieldname='b'`. Your update doesn't provide any illumination for me either - is that meant to be the input or the result? Either way, can you produce the other one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is even not possible logically.

For any record if the value of fieldname is 'a' then fieldname can not have value 'b' (i.e. fieldname = 'a' then fieldname != 'b'). That means fieldname can not have more than one value for a single record.

If you write `WHERE fieldname = 'a' AND fieldname = 'b' AND fieldname = 'c'` it will give you empty result.

So there is no way to shorthand `AND`.