# SQL Match table and multiple columns

Tags: sql

I wanted to know a Query where in which i want to locate a specific table that contains two or more columns:

I tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM DB 
WHERE TableName = 'TableName' 
AND ColumName in('column1' , 'column2')
```

But this query will look if any of those columns are there, but i want it to return only if all of them are a match.

I hope this questions makes sense.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-columns-table.html

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Teradata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator `IN` is a concatenation of OR. However, there's no way to creare a short concatenation of `AND` as well.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481192/multiple-or-statement-can-be-written-as-in-any-way-for-multiple-and-statement-i).

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you in `MySQL`:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME in ('column1','column2') 
AND TABLE_SCHEMA='your_database'
GROUP BY table_name
HAVING COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) =2;
```